# What are credit cards, debit cards, and other types of cards?

Tags: credit-card, terminology, debit-card

[This question right here](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/119878/what-are-the-pros-and-cons-of-a-credit-card-for-a-european) and the plethora of comments in it reminded me of something that I've found annoying for a long, long time. Seems that depending on where you come from the terms "credit card" and "debit card" can mean many wildly different things. They certainly differ a lot between US and EU, and it seems that even who has issued them might be a factor. I've also seen names like "charge card" on this site, which I suspect is something even different.

So - is there a comprehensive list (or perhaps someone willing to attempt one in this thread) with all the different meanings (and implications) of these terms, depending on location, issuer, moon phase, etc?

**To clarify:** The basic idea of "credit cards let you borrow money; debit cards only let you spend what you put on them" is pretty simple and clear. But in different places in the world there are a lot of more subtle differences.

For example, what I already learned from the few answers that have been posted here, in the US you cannot access your credit card account directly. You can see balance, you can pay it off, but you cannot treat it like another bank account. I've also read between the lines that credit cards might be issued not only by banks but other businesses too.

This contrasts with my experience here in the EU, where I haven't heard of a card that hasn't been issued by a bank; and it's the bank account that has the credit feature, not the card. I can treat the credit card account just like a regular account, I can keep extra money there, send and receive money via internet banking, etc.

And I'm sure there are other differences as well. That's what I'm after - a list of regional (or otherwise) differences in the details of how the cards work and how they can be used.

Comment: Vix: Can you give any pointers / links that illustrate your belief that credit-cards (CCs) can be "_just like a regular account_"? I'm from the UK and I'm not recognising your description of CCs (either from the question or your comments to answers). I can use a CC at online shops; through online banking I can view CC statements and pay-down a CC. I'm not aware of being able to _send_ money from a CC through online banking (although to be honest, I've never really looked). However, the account behind it is certainly not _just like a regular bank account_.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by your distinction between US and EU credit cards. I certainly can use my US credit card account to pay bills online. I can make partial payments and I can "withdraw money", i.e. get a cash advance. Yes, I can't "store extra money" there. Well, some credit cards let me pay more than I owe and then record it as a "credit balance". Others just won't allow me to overpay. What can you do with your EU card that I can't do with a US card?

Comment: Well, that's just the thing - my CC account _is_ a regular bank account. Or, well, I haven't run into a place where it would behave differently. In particular, I can enter my internet bank and both of those accounts have account numbers and are shown next to each other. When I make a money transfer, there's a dropdown where I can select either account. I can send money either way from one account to the other (even going into debt on the CC account); etc.

Comment: I'd be interested to know what EU country you are talking about, because I concur with @TripeHound that it certainly isn't the way you describe in the UK. Credit cards cannot be operated like bank accounts, and there are plenty of "non-bank" providers. Indeed on the latter point I can be certain that you are wrong: American Express for example [operates in just about every EU country](https://www.americanexpress.com/change-country/).

Comment: I almost wonder if you've made a mistake, and that what you think is a credit card is actually a bank account with a debit card and overdraft facility. The fact that you seem to think that "debit cards only let you spend what you put on them" (which is wrong) supports this theory.

Comment: I'll add something which may help clarify a bit (US): my debit card can be used as "credit" in a computer system, which means that the withdrawal might be delayed a bit and I can't really do cashback. This sounds a bit like what you are describing as a credit card. However, I have another card, my credit card, which is not tied to any bank account, is through a company which only does credit cards and is not a bank, and which is effectually a loan I have to pay back every month or else receive 20%+ in interest.

Comment: There are a lot of answers already but none seem to cover what I've seen is a card which apparently could be used "as debit or credit".  I think this was in the USA.

Comment: @JBentley - Is there a way to check what kind of a card it is? Here's an [anonymized picture of them](http://valts.21.lv/problem/cards.jpg). One clearly says "debit", the other - "credit".

Comment: @Vilx-: for checking what kind of card, please see the link at the end of my answer. The card type is encoded in the first part of the card number (in the first 6 digits of the card number). From what is written on the cards, I'd guess one is a credit card and the other a debit card. So far, I've never consciously encountered a card that "outward" had credit and debit signs on it. But then I don't have more to do with credit cards than the average European who every once in a while is in North America for professional reasons (and my profession is not banking/finance, neither).

Comment: @JBentley: "plenty of non-bank providers": of course, we also have credit card companies that don't have the look & feel of a bank - nevertheless they may actually be a bank. In Germany the law regarding payment services says that anyone who's in the credit business is a bank ("Kreditinstitut") and needs a banking license (as opposed to payment services who need a different license). I don't know about AmEx, but e.g Paypal Europe is a bank.

Comment: @cbeleitessupportsMonica - Hmm, well, all I can say then is that my card is a MasterCard, because digit 1 is a `5`. I knew that. After that there's just a bank number and an account number. So, I guess then there's no (easy) way to tell what my card looks like to the payment networks.

Comment: @Vilx- I tried some more BIN checkers (only ones that work with the first 6 digits...), and got somewhat inconsistent results, e.g. one said prepaid credit where others said debit... But then again, this may be a result of the German card terms not aligning too well with the US terminology (and that card has neither credit nor debit printed on; it is also not valid any more). As for your cards, as they actually say "credit" and "debit" respectively, I'd probably trust that...

Comment: When I was a kid, decades ago, in the United States, Diner's Club and American Express were "charge cards" that had to be paid off in full each  month, and Master Charge (now Master Card) were "credit cards"

Comment: @GalacticCowboy Would be great if that was covered in an answer!

Comment: Worth noting that at least in the US, debit cards also go by the name "check cards".

Comment: Your question doesn't seem to indicate any understanding of credit card rewards, which are the primary reason I own a credit card as a US citizen. Other than my mortgage, I don't pay interest on anything ever, _especially_ not on my credit cards. I pay them off in full every month. Borrowing money to spend more than I have is NOT why I use credit cards. I use credit cards for all purchases because of the rewards they give me. That's the main reason. The other reason is to build credit, but now that I have an excellent credit score, I don't really care about that either.

Comment: @Vilx- wrote "even going into debt on the CC account" That's the point of the credit card. Generally, any and all use of a credit card puts you in debt on the credit card account. You basically just said "My credit card lets me use it like a credit card."

Comment: "in the US you cannot access your credit card account directly" I don't even understand what that means

Comment: @Kevin Same.. why is this something OP would need to do? Your credit card's website or app tells you how much you owe, and you can pay your bill. There's no other function to having a credit card in the US.

Comment: @MarkStewart Amex cards are still charge cards to this day, but personally, I've never understood the distinction. If you don't pay off an Amex each month, you get charged a fee. This is basically the same as having to pay interest...

Answer (score 21):

**EU** and more specifically **Germany**:

(Colloquial) terminology is roughly: the card automatically issued by your bank is the "bank card", and cards issued by e.g. Visa, Mastercard, Diners, American Express are "credit card" (I'd almost say that credit card [EN-US] vs. DE Kreditkarte is a false friend).

- the debit cards automatically issued with a [checking] bank account are often co-branded with a domestic debit payment system (Germany: girocard aka EC-card) and an international debit card system such as V-Pay (VISA) or Maestro (Mastercard).
  At least in German, they are colloquially referred to by bank card rather than debit card, and are thought of as something quite separate form a credit card (even if they have Visa V-Pay or Mastercard Maestro debit card branding).

  - At the POS, the merchand can choose which mode is preferred, and that will usually be the domestic system since from what I've heard transaction fees are typically domestic system < international debit system < credit card.

  If the bank (checking) account has an Überziehungskredit (overdraft credit line; having such a credit line is pretty much standard here - in fact, a customer may have to actively request it being set to 0 if they don't want it), then also the bank card can withdraw more than the actual account balance (up to that overdraft limit possibly even a bit further "geduldete Überziehung" [tolerated overdraft]).
  I think the overdraft interest may have the role here of credit card interest in the US, though credit card (in the US sense of the word) credit has even higher interest.
- What is referred to as Kreditkarte (credit card) over here comprises what is referred to as credit card in the US, but you'll also find Visa/Mastercard Debit cards among the choice of Kreditkarten a bank offers.

  The latter are sometimes called "Kreditkarte auf Guthabenbasis" ("credit card based on positive balance") or Debit-Kreditkarte or "prepaid Kreditkarte" or "aufladbare Kreditkarte" (chargeable, same term as for batteries)
- Even among the proper credit cards (I use as definition: a card with credit line, a card that is of type "credit" according to IIN/BIN, see below), there's a wide range of settings possible behind the scenes (i.e. not visible for POS, just between card holder and their bank/issuer).
  I think the one I have serves well in showing possible differences:

  - Similar to what Vilx- says, my credit card account behaves quite like another bank account (or subaccount): I can push money there, and pull money from there - though in my case only to and from the main checking account (but similar behaviour I have e.g. with the account at a broker's where allowing money to leave only to my pre-specified account is a safety feature). I even *get* interest for a positive balance on the credit card account (nowadays it's of course in good approximation 0).
  - The credit card account also has some *credit*.
  - At a POS, the available credit that shows up if there's a positive balance on the credit card account is balance + credit limit, so in that respect the card behaves similarly to a *debit card*, and even more similar to the bank card.
  - like described for a *charge card* in @RonJohn's answer for the US, if the balance runs into the negative, it is paid fully at the next billing date (once per month). This happens automatically by withdrawing from the connected checking account.
  - The difference to the bank card is slight: if I buy with the bank card, I immediately see the money withdrawn from the checking account. If I buy with the credit card, I (almost) immediately see the money withdrawn from the credit card subaccount. Though if that runs into the negative, I won't pay interest until the next due date whereas checking account overdraft (e.g. via bank card payment) immediately costs interest.

  This particular behaviour of course depends on the actual contract you have with your bank. There are also credit cards that internally work more closely to what the inner workings of a credit card are in the US.

I don't have numbers, but I'd suspect that credit cards in the US sense are rare here compared to debit/charge contracts. As a slight indicator, comparison web pages put warnings to offers that have only automated minimum payments as opposed to automatically withdrawing the full amount due.

Update: [Visa](https://www.visa.de/bezahlen-mit-visa/produkte.html#3) says charge cards are the most common form of credit cards in Germany. (They literally write "credit card" here - whereas they say debit card aka bank card and "prepaid cards are payment cards that ...") [This (German) newspaper article from 2014](https://www.faz.net/aktuell/finanzen/meine-finanzen/geld-ausgeben/kreditkarten-boom-kreditkarten-kommen-oft-teuer-zu-stehen-12996029.html) says: 105 mio. bank (debit) cards plus 28 mio. Kreditkarten, of which 24 mio. are charge cards. So on average 1 "proper" credit card per ≈ 20 inhabitants vs. 1.3 bank cards per inhabitant.

---

The retailer can know what type of a card they have in front of them, as that is encoded in the card number (IIN/BIN = 1st 6 digits AFAIK). There are  data bases (e.g. [here](https://www.bindb.com/bin-database.html) or [here](https://www.bincodes.com/bin-checker/)) that list what the BIN means, including card type.
I do think though, that our bank cards have a totally separate numbering system - at least I didn't find information how/where to find the BIN in that type of card number (and putting the first 6 digits into one of the BIN checkers above yields balderdash or "invalid number")

---

Is suspect an additional difference may be in the size of credit card credit. 
From what I read for Germany, 2 month's net wages (≈ 1 - 1.5 month's gross wage) is a typical limit. (And web pages remind people to make sure the credit limit on their credit card is raised to at least 1000 - 2000 € if traveling abroad). I think the combination of charge card with the possibility to push money to the card in order to temporarily raise the available limit means that the proper limit can be comparably low. In contrast I gather that in the US, credit card limits are typically far larger - but I may be wrong (on both the German and the US numbers).

Incidentally, the same 2 month's net wages is said as a rule of thumb for the checking account overdraft limit (or reserve line of credit, see @MSalters' comment).

Comment: In the EU, do Mastercard and Visa directly issue cards, or do they come from second parties? In the USA, American Express issues their own cards, but as far as I can tell both Visa and Mastercard operate exclusively through second parties such as banks and major financial houses.

Comment: @GalacticCowboy: Both of them say "we don't issue cards ourselves, please talk to a bank" (Visa in addition says, or to Ikea).

Comment: Regarding your last paragraph: If you have a German Girocard you can find the co-branded international debit system number on the magnetic stripe track 2 (while the information for the German girocard system is on track 3). This number can then be entered into one of the BIN data bases (it's a normal Mastercard / Visa debit card number). I am not aware of any way to figure it out without a magnetic card reader though (you can not infer it from the girocard / account number as far as I know).

Comment: @Hans: my girocards have a tiny printed "card number" on the back (not the large  IBAN), but the BIC lookup didn't work with the first 6 of these. Those numbers don't have 12 digits like my credit card number, though. Of course they must be electronically readable if the card is to work internationally. I also have a corporate "credit" card that is actually a debit card (no subaccount, amounts are directly taken off the checking account) taht otherwise looks and feels like a credit card, incl. 12 digit number plainly on front plus a 3 digit validation code, and BIC lookup worked for that one.

Comment: @cbeleites: Yeah, I also have this "card number". I think this is just used for some bank-internal processes. I don't recall seeing it anywhere on the mag stripe, so it's not really needed for processing anyway.

Comment: "I think the overdraft interest may have the role here of credit card interest in the US" – In Germany, is it considered normal and common to overdraw a checking account on purpose merely for the sake of convenience? In the US, overdraft fees are usually pretty big (around $40 per transaction), so it would be completely unimaginable to, say, overdraw your account in order to buy a can of Coke.

Comment: @TannerSwett: you caught me: I've never done it, so I cannot speak from experience. And money is something "one doesn't talk about" here. However, I checked the price lists of a few banks and they listed overdraft interest but no additional fees. This web page https://kontist.com/posts/dispokredit-vorteil-risiko says that by law such a overdraft credit line (Dispositionskredit) may cost interest but no additional fees. The citation is a bit vague, and at a quick glance I didn't find this as a totally fixed rule in that law (i.e. as I read it, fees may be possible with additional paperwork).

Comment: @TannerSwett: As I understand it, in many EU countries checking accounts have or can have the equivalent of what the US calls a _reserve line of credit_. You don't get hit by overdraft fees if you're overdrawn, but still above the reserve line. You'd still pay interest on any credit actively used, but the unused reserve would cost at worst a small annual fee. My bank would charge 12.9% APR for it, assuming I repay it within a month. In effect this is a pretty cheap payday loan.

Comment: I tried to find statistics on overdraft credit lines, but I found only numbers for people in public debt counseling due to debt overload. Of those, 30  % had such an overdraft credit line, and the average debt in that category was ≈ 1800 €. However, in my experience pretty much anyone with some sort of income automatically gets such an overdraft credit automatically when opening a bank account (I got one as a student on a scholarship). Not having one means either that you actively requested the bank to set as well as their internal tolerated overdraft to zero (they have to do that, but in my..

Comment: ... experience it can take some discussion) or that due to your debt situation, the bank canceled that credit line. Which is the far more probable reason for people in debt counseling to not have such a credit line. Also, the bank may first reduce the amount (by law they have to keep that credit in a sensible relation to the customer's general financial situation). So all in all, the information about usage of such credit people who are not overloaded by debt is rather limited.

Comment: @MSalters: the German variety (called Dispositionskredit, short Dispo) does not charge any fees on not using this credit, only interest on the amount of credit used.

Comment: @MSalters: You pay interest on a negative balance (credit extended and used) even if paid off within a month?  Ok, then I guess USA credit cards do allow cash withdrawal and transfers under pretty much the same terms (interest starts accruing immediately, no grace period).  For us, that's a very abnormal usage of a credit card -- when making genuine purchases processed through the credit card network, there's a grace period (and it doesn't even start until the monthly statement) and if you pay the balance before the end of the grace period, there's no interest.

Comment: @BenVoigt: Correct. So for a one week €100 overdraft you might pay €0.25. Note: this applies to debit cards. For credit cards, overdrafts only start after the grace period, but they're likely more expensive (higher APR) so it makes sense to pay the full CC bill even if that sends your checking account into overdraft.

Answer (score 16):

This is accurate for the USA.

https://www.investopedia.com/terms/c/chargecard.asp

> A charge card is a type of electronic payment card that **charges no interest** but requires the user to **pay his/her balance in full upon receipt of the statement**, usually on a monthly basis. Charge cards are offered by a limited number of issuers.

https://www.nerdwallet.com/blog/nerdscholar/credit-card/

> A credit card allows you to borrow money from a bank to make purchases, whether you’re buying a burger or a round-trip ticket to France. As long as you pay back the money you borrow within the “grace period” of 25-30 days, you don’t have to pay extra. If you don’t pay it back in that time period, you’ll have to pay interest — a percentage of the money you owe the bank — on top of what you borrowed.

Credit cards are a form of **revolving credit** (which according to Google is "credit that is automatically renewed as debts are paid off").

Credit card accounts are **not** tied to deposit accounts at the same bank.  (I didn't mention this originally, because the concept is completely foreign in the US.)  One exception is the the notion of the *Secured* credit card.  In that case, you make a deposit into a *savings* account, and the bank pays itself from that account **only if** you default on the credit card account.  Secured cards are the purview of (typically young) people with little credit history, and people with established **but bad** credit history.

Originally, American Express only issued charge cards, but now they also issue credit cards.

**Debit cards** are linked directly to a bank account.  When you pay for something, the money comes directly out of your (usually) checking account.  If you try to buy something worth more than your bank balance, the bank has the choice of either #1 declining it, or #2 accepting it, and charging you a (quite steep) *non-sufficient funds* fee.

Comment: This is nice, but not the full picture. If you read the comments, it seems that the type of the card you use can also affect the merchants that you buy things from. From what I gather by reading on the internet, it seems that in the USA you even need to select the type of card (credit/debit) you're using when paying at the store. Why would that be?

Comment: In addition, it also seems that in the USA you cannot use the same account for your credit card and, say, salary deposits. The banks don't like (for whatever reason) having a positive balance on credit cards. In contrast, in Europe (or at least in my country) that's not an issue. A credit card account is an account like any other - just that you may go negative.

Comment: @Vilx- I've never tried to treat a credit card as debit, or vice versa, and have always *presumed* that it's because the retail vendor can't know whether a card is debit or credit.

Comment: @Vilx- credit cards are backed by *loans* in the US. Loans aren't meant to carry a positive deposit balance, so the concept of "depositing" money into a loan (i.e. via direct deposit of your salary) doesn't really make sense. Debit cards are backed by a deposit account (usually a checking account, sometimes a savings account) so you can deposit money into the account behind a debit card. I'm in the middle of typing an answer that addresses your first comment.

Comment: @Vilx- "in the USA you cannot use the same account for your credit card and, say, salary deposits."  In the USA, that is an **invalid question**, because credit cards are not tied to bank accounts.

Comment: Well, now, that's something new! I never imagined that they could be NOT tied to bank accounts.

Comment: Strictly speaking, a credit card *is* tied to an account, but it's a special kind of loan account that can only be accessed via the card(s) attached to it.

Comment: See, it's all these little details that I want to understand, because most of the time that's where the real issues are. The general idea of credit/debit cards  is indeed simple, but the variations in implementations are so wildly varying that it often becomes difficult to even talk about these things with people from another country.

Comment: @Vilx- yes, credit card accounts are completely divorced from deposit accounts.  Having CC issued by the same bank as your deposit account is arbitrary, and no way a requirement.

Comment: @Vilx- I edited my answer to mention that, and also describe secured credit cards.

Comment: I didn't mean that credit cards need to be tied to a deposit account. I meant that they _are_ an account by themselves. Like, I can go to my internet bank and there's an account, number and all, for my credit card. I can pay my electricity bill by sending money over from that account, without involving the card at all. Even going into debt. Just like I'd send money over from "regular" (debit?) bank account. It's like... the account is the foundation, and then there can be one or more cards attached to it... and it's the account that has the debt feature, not the card.

Comment: And in the USA you can't do that right? You cannot access a credit card account like a regular bank account, correct?

Comment: @Vilx- dogs are alive, spinach is alive.  Why can't I put  my spinach on a leash and take it for a walk?  Because, while dogs and spinach are both alive, they are fundamentally different creatures.  Ditto credit cards and deposit accounts.

Comment: I didn't mean to contradict you, sorry. I just wanted to understand the differences between EU and USA (or maybe just my bank?) better. Right now it looks like I have a spinach that can walk and bark, and I'm confused that not all spinaches can do that.

Comment: *Like, I can go to my internet bank and there's an account, number and all, for my credit card. I can pay my electricity bill by sending money over from that account, without involving the card at all.* To be clear, many banks that issue credit cards in the US allow all of those same functions. In fact, I paid my electric bill from my credit card via the issuer's internet banking website a few hours ago. The only difference is that the credit card account is strictly a loan and it's not normal to be able to carry a positive balance on it.

Comment: @dwizum: In the US yes you can have checks that (eventually) draw on a credit card, but making a withdrawal from a credit card account without going through the payment network almost always get punished with high "balance transfer" or "cash advance" fees.  There are also "line of credit" accounts that don't disfavor transfers (and they typically have a "credit access card" which runs on a credit card network but is treated by regulation much more like a debit card), consumers would rarely have one but they are common for businesses.

Comment: @dwizum: You wrote a comment about a credit card account in the USA equipped with online banking that allowed a "push" payment to your electric company.  That sounds like a check (or electronic draft) because credit card processing networks are not capable of "push" initiated by the cardholder.  Doing that without incurring a "balance transfer" charge, in the US at least, usually requires a "line of credit" and cannot be done with a "credit card".

Comment: @BenVoigt  Oh, okay, that makes sense, although it's not directly applicable for the example I gave. My credit union uses a bill pay service that pushes such payments through the appropriate card network (Mastercard in this case) to merchants who accept bill payments via credit cards.

Comment: @Vilx- You can do what you're describing with a CC, but it works a little differently. If you want to pay for something online, you wouldn't enter a bank account number to make a payment, you would enter your _credit card number_ instead (along with personal info like your name and address). This is the standard way Americans buy things online. Doing this puts a negative balance on your CC, which you can view and pay on the CC issuer's website or app. There is no way to "withdraw" or "deposit" money. Those terms don't make any sense when talking about CCs.

Comment: Many banks allow a third option in case the account backing the debit card lacks sufficient funds: automatic transfer from another linked account.  e.g. my debit card is attached to my checking account, but if I run out of money, the balance will be automatically transferred from my savings.  There is, however, a statutory limit to the number of transfers that are allowed per month.

Comment: I have often used my credit card to transfer money to my checking account at the same bank, or to withdraw funds from an ATM.  Sometimes I pay a small ATM fee, but not always, and _never_ any other fee.

Comment: @WGroleau if you're in the US, that sounds like a cash advance.

Comment: @RonJohn, exactly.  I mention it in opposition to the allegation that a cash advance has a high fee, and the allegation that funds can’t be transferred from a CC to another account.

Comment: @WGroleau I understand how to get **cash** from a CC at an ATM machine, but how do you transfer it to a checking account without then redepositing it using a debit card?

Comment: I transfer from one account to another with the bank’s online web form.  They don’t care what kind of account.  I can also transfer that way between accounts at different banks (though I haven’t yet tried that with my CC account).  I can also transfer into/out of Apple Pay (which is in reality just another bank account).

Answer (score 13):

Other answers cover the differences between the *types* of card (debit vs credit vs charge). However, there's another layer of important differences - **the card processing network and the processing method used for a specific transaction.** In some cases, this can cause card types to behave differently on a transaction by transaction basis.

When you swipe a card, the merchant uses their own bank to collect money for your transaction. Their bank talks to a card processing network (Visa, Mastercard, etc) in order to submit the transaction to your bank, i.e. the bank that issued the card.

Most card networks handle many different types of cards. For instance, VISA handles debit cards, gift cards, and credit cards. Further, over time, the features of those cards have evolved and changed over time, and different issuing banks may issue different card products that have different features (as an example, in the past, data about the card was encoded on mag stripes, whereas now, cards generally also have a chip on them). Even within the context of a single card, a merchant may be able to submit the transaction different ways:

- via reading the magstripe,
- reading the chip,
- manually typing the card number into a console,
- using a stored token from a prior transaction,
- reading a contactless chip in the card,
- communicating with a payment app on a cellphone or smart watch which has been linked to the card.

Further, some networks allow a transaction against a debit card to be submitted via their debit card channel, **or** via their credit card channel.

Most of this is invisible to consumers because it happens automatically, but some merchants essentially put the consumer in direct control. For instance, in many grocery stores, the clerk checking you out will ring up your items, and there will be a POS console in the checkout line facing the customer. The customer will swipe or insert their card and actually carry out the transaction - the store clerk never actually sees or touches your card. Often, this arrangement puts the choice of transaction style in the consumer's hands - you can choose to swipe the magstripe or read the chip. If the network your card is on allows transactions on your card type to be submitted via different channels, you will sometimes be presented with that choice (for instance, you may be prompted to choose to submit the transaction as a debit or credit transaction, although the choices presented on the console rarely actually spell that out - instead they often say something cryptic like "US MASTERCARD" for submitting a credit transaction).

Ultimately, the end result is still the same from a consumer's perspective - the transaction hits your account and the merchant is paid. However, there are a few differences from the bank and merchants' perspectives:

- different transaction types will incur different interchange fees. A merchant may receive slightly less money for a "card not present" debit card transaction versus a chip-read credit transaction.
- different types will result in different responsibilities from a fraud perspective. If the transaction is submitted in a way that's considered more secure, the banks assume a larger portion of the risk, versus the merchant. This is often an incentive for merchants to prefer more secure transaction types.
- different types will result in different timings for the money actually leaving your account. Many banks run credit card transactions in real-time but batch debit card transactions.

I'm adding an edit to address additional points you made in your edit to the question:

> For example, what I already learned from the few answers that have been posted here, in the US you cannot access your credit card account directly. You can see balance, you can pay it off, but you cannot treat it like another bank account.

In the US, cards *of any type* are essentially just instruments for accessing an account. Typically, card types and account types are strictly linked: a debit card can *only* be linked to a deposit account, and a credit card can *only* be linked to a credit card loan account. There are other subtle variations on this theme though - for instance, some institutions will issue a special kind of credit card linked to a line of credit instead of a traditional credit card loan. And even more confusingly, there are cases where other mechanisms traditionally linked only to deposit accounts can be linked to loans (for instance, a bank may allow checks to be written against a home equity line of credit).

It's also important to point out that cards (of any time) are not inherently linked 1 to 1 to accounts. In other words, if you have a deposit (checking) account, you can have no debit card at all. Or one debit card. Or 4 debit cards, with different card numbers and different people's names on them. The same holds true with credit cards - one person who opens a credit card can add other users to their loan, and have the bank issue each of them their own card. All the cards are tied to the same credit card loan, and transactions on all of them end up impacting that single loan.

> I've also read between the lines that credit cards might be issued not only by banks but other businesses too.

It's common for various merchants to issue cards with their own branding (i.e. the retailer Target has their own credit card). Sometimes, these cards are "private" in the sense that they can *only* be used at that merchant. But other times, the branded card can be used anywhere (for instance, Amazon issues cards that can be used anywhere, but earn extra rewards if used to buy things from Amazon). Confusingly, these cards can be implemented in many different ways:

- sometimes these cards are actually *operated by the merchant* directly. No bank or network is involved.
- sometimes the cards are co-branded with a network, and use that network to submit transactions (i.e. Amazon's VISA card product).
- sometimes the cards are operated by a third party bank, even though it's the merchant who "issues" the cards to consumers (for instance, the hardware store Lowes has a private account that's operated by a third party bank).

> I can treat the credit card account just like a regular account, I can keep extra money there, send and receive money via internet banking, etc.

It's important to clarify that, largely speaking, this is mostly true in the US as well. For instance, if you get a credit card from Bank of America (or just about any other bank), you can use their internet banking tools to manage the account. This can mean doing things like paying your credit card bill, or sometimes even things like using your credit card to submit payments or "transfer" money (essentially taking a cash advance from the card) to other accounts. In fact, if you use one bank for your credit card and your deposit accounts (say, a checking account into which you have your paycheck direct deposited) you can typically log in to one internet banking console and manage your various accounts from one place, even though they are technically separate accounts. So, in practice, you *do* usually have access to the account, it's just treated separately from your other accounts.

The one clear differentiating factor is that the loan behind a credit card is a distinct and separate account from your deposit accounts or other loans. This is important due to the way the US banking system manages reserves and other operational and financial concerns. Banks in the US are required to keep a certain amount of cash on hand, based on the types and balances of accounts they operate. This cash on hand generally falls into two categories:

- Reserves to protect against losses from loans. If a consumer defaults on a loan, the bank needs to have cash to offset that loss. Banks are required to reserve against these losses to make sure they can continue operation when they have losses.
- Reserves to protect against withdrawals from deposit accounts. Banks need to keep cash on hand so they can give it to consumers who withdraw it from deposit accounts, in order to stay liquid if or when consumers want to use their money.

**These two types of reserves are calculated and managed very differently.** Because of this dual approach to reserves, banks need to have a strict separation between account types. If a bank were to offer a *single* product that let consumers use an account in either state at will (either as a loan, if they charge a lot of credit transactions, *or* as a deposit account if they put a lot of money into the account such that it has a positive balance), that account type would be impossible to reserve for, in our current model.

So, banks maintain strict separation between account types. Actions that are normally associated with a deposit account (depositing a check, direct deposit of your salary, etc) aren't allowed on loan accounts, and carrying a positive balance on a credit card isn't typical. Also, actions that are typical on a credit card (running a "negative" balance) aren't allowed on deposit accounts, and banks take measures to prevent them (charging overdraft fees, blocking transactions, etc.).

Comment: In Euorpe, or at least in Poland, it is common for banks to offer a "debit limit" - esentially a

Comment: The co-branded Visa/Mastercard cards are usually issued by banks. For example, there is a Chase Visa co-branded with Amazon, and a Goldman Sachs Mastercard co-branded with Apple.

Comment: "When you swipe a card" The term "swipe" is used specifically to using the magnetic stripe. "Most card networks handle many different types of cards. For instance, VISA handles debit cards, gift cards, and credit cards." Visa Inc. is different from VisaNet. VisaNet is a network. Visa Inc. is a company that includes not only VisaNet, but issuer processing, acquirer processing, ATM driving, etc.

Comment: My bank debit card says "Mastercard" on it. Is Visa still involved as the processor?

Comment: The relationship between credit cards and banks has always confused me, because I almost never got a credit card from a bank I was already doing business with. I signed up for AT&T Universal Card decades ago, and I think it has moved from bank to bank over the years (I manage the card on the Citi web site). A few months ago I signed up for Delta Sky Miles, they sent me a credit card; it has the American Express logo on it.

Comment: *When you swipe a card* — is this still a thing?  I thought even the USA had finally moved to chip?

Comment: @Barmar - if it says Mastercard on it, then Mastercard is the processor. I used VISA as an example in my text out of convenience. Cards only ever have one processor associated with them, and cards are (usually) branded prominently with that processor's name and logo.

Comment: @Barmar - what you're discussing is the co-branding I mentioned. Some companies literally issue their own cards (i.e. Target effectively acts as it's own issuing bank) while many other companies get a bank to run a card that they brand (your AT&T card is really issued and operated by Citibank). The branding and issue/operation are separate from the processing network (i.e. Mastercard). Even more confusingly, some financial institutions operate as both an issuing bank AND a processing network (i.e. American Express).

Comment: Now I understand. It always confused me when I heard that you should call your bank to resolve credit card problems, when they were never issued by "my" bank. It's just whatever bank the issuing company happens to use to run their branded cards, I had no choice in the matter (although I see that my bank does issue credit cards as well).

Comment: @Acccumulation indeed you are correct, I was trying to avoid getting an already long-winded answer too far down into the weeds and used the name "Visa" because I felt it would be more easily recognizable than "VisaNet" to people who are familiar with the "VISA" branding on a card and aren't familiar with the inner structures of the actual company.

Comment: Nice one, especially that last point about reserve accounting in the US! That explains SO MUCH! Also, I was under the impression that the credit card networks are just... sort of intermediaries. It's the banks that actually have the accounts with the money and that give out the loans and what not. However if each bank handled their own cards, then each merchant would have to have separate integrations with each bank's systems in order to accept their cards. So the credit card networks (Visa, MasterCard, Amex, etc) were created to simplify this. [contd.]

Comment: Now you only need to integrate with a network and you can process all the cards from all the banks that are a part of it. And there are other intermediaries too which have integrations with all the major networks, so the merchants actually ever only need to deal with one intermediary, who deals with all the networks, who deal with all the banks. The networks still force some rules though. For example, I know that they strictly forbid merchants to use different prices for card transactions vs other methods (say, cash). So merchants cannot put a "card fee" to their customers who pay with cards.

Comment: @Vilx- And even _that_ isn't universally true - in Michigan and possibly other US states, it's legal for filling stations to charge more for gasoline purchased by card than the same fuel purchased by cash.  Before you ask, I have no idea how or why this particular exception happened, but it did.

Comment: Technically it's allowed to discount for a given payment method (i.e. 5 cents off a gallon if you pay with cash), but you can't literally mark up or charge extra for a different method (you can't say, 5 cents extra if you pay with credit card). Of course the end result for the consumer is the same. @Vilx- - you've got it right with respect to how networks operate, they're intermediaries. The consumer has an *issuing bank* that holds the card's account, and the merchant has a *merchant bank* that holds it's account, and those banks integrate with the networks to process payments.

Comment: And yes, @Vilx- - the impact of reserve banking is pretty significant in terms of how account types are handled in the US.

Answer (score 8):

I can see why it is confusing, but part of it is that  you do not have your facts correct.

### A credit card is a loan

With a credit card, you have a whole special *revolving credit* account.  When you make charges, it adds to the loan amount that you owe.  It's an account where the balance is usually zero or negative.

And monthly, you "pay off the loan" in part or in full, by making a money transfer from one of your deposit accounts, to the credit card account.

It is not connected with any deposit account (checking or savings account) where you normally store money; although affiliation with a bank where you have deposit accounts can help you qualify for their credit card.  The criteria for qualifying for a credit card is fairly high, as the bank is trusting you with their money.

### A debit card let you instantly withdraw from your deposit account

You can only have a debit card if have a deposit account of some kind (checking, savings, etc).  The qualifications for this are lower than for a credit card; and you generally qualify unless you have a history of abuse of deposit accounts.

The debit card lets you instantly withdraw money and give it to the merchant.  It's that simple.

### However, debit cards had a problem

As of the 1980s, **credit** card processing was a trust system, done offline on paper or in "nightly batches" electronically, and the bank system absorbed the risk of fraud. Merchants had to phone their acquirer (bank's) service center to get large-value charges approved.  Obviously, this evolved; later you touch-toned in the card number, later the swipe machine would use a phone dialer and modem to get the charge approved (except for small ones), and later the Internet would replace the dialer.  But the "batch/offline" processing infrastructure has never gone away -- that's how you can pay for a dining-car meal inside a tunnel.  This system entails more risk; someone could use a canceled card for small transactions that aren't "phoned home". That risk was divided between banks and merchants (generally banks underwrote the risk using the merchant fees as forced "insurance").

The **debit** card was built much more mindful of the idea of being "always and only online".  This was a mandate in the US, but it varied by country. Again, the risk was folded into the merchant fees.  In the US they kept these fees quite low, but, online was mandatory. (ATM/Debit terminals were heavily marketed to merchants who had never before taken *credit* cards because they disliked the 2-4% merchant fees).  Early on, that became a huge impediment to adoption, as only large corporations like BP gas or McDonalds would put in the IT infrastructure (they already had it for business reasons).  But for small businesses like Joe's Chinese Takeaway, it was not practicable even into the 00's.

As a result, at least in the United States, many business would not accept debit cards, but would accept credit cards.

But this evolved into "debit" payment networks such as Maestro... *Being what they are*, these networks were naturals to merge into the *credit card* clearinghouse system, as it was building out the same infastructure; hence Maestro looks a lot like Mastercard.  Obviously, maintaining two systems has its disadvantages; and they are looking to factor them down to one network.

In 20/20 hindsight, the "always-on" method makes perfect sense, and the "batch" / "offline" method of credit cards seems insane. But universal constant-connection Internet is only a recent development of the last 15 years or so, and is still not true everywhere.  In those cases, the credit system still supports offline, and pure Debit does not.

### A debit card with Visa/Mastercard/etc.

Consumers wanted to be able to use their debit cards anywhere credit cards were accepted.  So in the early 1990s banks experimented with a Mastercard-branded ATM card, which allowed charges to be processed either way -- as an ATM card, or as a credit card.  If a merchant did not take ATM card, the transaction could still be processed.  The bank absorbed all the risk, so it was reluctantly offered to high-credit-rating customers.

This proved to be a wild success.  As the industry got experience with it, they got experience with the risks, extended the credit/debit card feature widely.  Today, everyone gets it by default *unless they decline it*.  Which a few do in the USA, because credit-mode transactions use signatures not PINs, which makes a credit-capable debit card a bomb.

Nomenclature wise (at least here in the US), a "plain" debit card was called an **ATM card** and a credit-mode-enabled debit card is called a **debit card**.

### Not to be confused with *prepaid cards*

A prepaid card is an entirely different animal.  It looks like a credit card, not a debit card, and works through the clearinghouse system like a credit card.  It is not tied to your deposit account; it's a whole separate account.  However it's not a loan; it doesn't go negative. You must prepay money into it before you can spend it (so in that sense it works sorta like a debit card). Prepaid cards are used for people who don't qualify for credit cards, don't have access to banking, are giving gift cards, or need to confine costs e.g. giving a subordinate a limited budget.

In summary, the debit immediately removes money from your deposit account; the money is gone.  The other gives you a loan for the amount you charged, and you need to "settle up that loan" at some point in the future.

Comment: In many European countries, debit cards were introduced in the late 70s or early 80s. They initially used paper slips – electronic transactions and ATMs came later. There was often a domestic debit card network, so merchants could accept debit cards but not credit cards. Some countries later replaced the network with international Visa/Mastercard networks.

Comment: @Jouni Thanks -- amended.

Comment: While your logic seems sensible, in Canada small places like convenience stores were and are more likely to take debit and not credit cards. Only large stores take credit cards. Many of us have "visa debit" which is a perfectly normal debit card connected to a bank account that can **pretend** to be a Visa card -- the transaction will go through that infrastructure -- in places like the US or online that will take Visa but not debit.

Answer (score 7):

A debit card is a card linked directly to a checking/savings account. If you use the card money is removed from the account almost instantaneously. And by instantaneously I mean from a few seconds to a few days.

A credit card is one that doesn't remove the funds immediately. Every 30/31 days they close the cycle, and you are billed for the amount you owe. These cards have a limit based on your income, and your credit history. If you can't pay the bill you will pay interest. If you don't pay at least a minimum amount you can also be hit with a penalty.  Once you hit your limit you can't charge any more  items until you pay down your balance. The question you linked to discusses the benefits of a credit card.

A charge card is similar to a credit card, except that you have to pay it off each month.

A gift card is a fixed amount of money on the card. When all the money is gone, you might be able to add more.

Comment: See my comments on RonJohn's answer.

Comment: Gift cards are just a special case of debit card, where (1) the linked account is not meant to ever be used directly, (2) the card often bears a generic name instead of the actual recipient/holder's name, and (3) ATM access is usually disallowed.

Comment: @BenVoigt Gift cards are generally prepaid or internal to the store.

Comment: @Acccumulation: "Debit cards" are "prepaid", it's drawing on money you have previously deposited.  But to add confusion to what should be simple, there's a category of "prepaid (debit) cards" designed for people whose financial history makes actual banks unwilling to do business with them.

Answer (score 6):

This is my experience as a consumer in France.

In France, cards are usually issued by your bank and tied to a specific bank account, and called "débit immédiat" or "débit différé".

Paying with a "débit immédiat" card will remove the amount from your bank account immediately (within seconds to a day or so). Not having the amount in your account may either lead to the purchase being refused or to your account being overdrawn (fees in that case are a whole different topic, but there is usually a permissible overdraft limit, and exceeding that limit brings higher fees, but even inside the limit you may not remain overdrawn for more than a matter of weeks before incurring more fees and significant problems, see below).

Paying with a "débit différé" card will remove the amount from your bank account the last day of the month, or the last day of the next month if the purchase is sufficiently close to the end of the current month. This is deemed useful since people are usually on monthly salaries paid slightly before the card balance is debited. For example, if the cutoff date is the 24th of the month, that gives you some six days to make sure that your expenses have not exceeded your paycheck. There may be a limit on the amount that you can rack up, in my experience usually defined by the class of card. This short-term loan does not accrue interest, though the fees for the card itself are generally significantly higher. The "débit différé" feature is often associated with higher prestige cards, with insurance, higher payment limits, etc. If you don't have enough money in your account, for example because your salary is late, your bank account gets overdrawn (unlike in some other countries where your account goes to zero and the amount remaining starts to accrue interest and/or fees).

There are also credit cards that work more like in the US, but they are much less popular and usually come with some kind of rewards program to make them interesting.

There is no concept of a credit rating that can be worked on using credit card strategies; it's very binary. If you default on loans (which includes having an overdraft for more than 60 days) you will be listed in the "FICP" files of the Banque de France (bad checks will get you in another file called "FCC"). The FICP files will be checked by any credit institution that offers you a loan; either you are there or you are not, I do not think there is any middle ground. This is known to create problems in some cases; for example restructuring your debt to lower your monthly payments to something you can better afford can be very hard if you have already started defaulting on the existing loans.

It is worth noting that France has its own payment network called "CB", and that most cards are dual use, either "CB - MasterCard" or "CB - Visa". Some banks offer only CB-MC or only CB-Visa, some banks offer both types. CB-only cards exist (or at least existed) but went from 22% of the market in 1997 to only 3% in 2009. This is totally transparent to consumers.

When you use a CB card, the CB payment terminals will not ask you if your want to use debit or credit, the payment goes through the CB network and the manner in which the debit is handled is purely on the side of the issuing bank.

Comment: Nice! This is different than the other answers and very useful!

Comment: I forgot to mention that there are also pre-paid cards, "cartes pré-payées". Those work as you'd expect (in other words, not unless there is enough money in the account to cover the transaction), and are in my experience given to kids by their parents. The big difference is that a pré-payée is "safe", while a débit immédiat will take the money out of your principal "checking" account, and the bank will usually be quite happy to let you overdraw your account and cash in the interest and penalties.

Answer (score 3):

In a comment you asked about the EU specifically, and while the other answers have very good and detailed descriptions of what the different types of cards are and their inner workings, there are some small(ish) differences in how they're used and how they're viewed. So this is not a complete answer (why add to the choir) but rather some extra information.

**In the US**, credit cards are used very extensively. The major payment method in the US are credit cards, followed by debit cards and cash, with cheques, and new developments like apple pay trailing behind. Everything that is not a credit card or cash is [considered an alternative method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternative_payments). In the US, you can technically live without a credit card but it will make life a lot less convenient.

Also, credit cards are used for marketing a lot, meaning that owning card A will get you a discount at company X, owning card B will you get you a discount at company Y etc. Owning multiple cards is common, and if you use your cards wisely, this will improve your *credit rating*.

Your credit rating is calculated from your credit use (but you can't know how, different topic) and is very important. It will determine how much credit you can have and this extends to getting mortgages, car loans and even stuff you and I might think unrelated, like renting an apartment. To improve your rating, you need to build a history with lenders, meaning that using your cards a lot but always be prompt in paying off your dues is the way to go. Not having a credit card, or not using it, will not build any history so it's a *negative* factor for your ability to borrow money.

Finally there is a culture surrounding credit cards in the US. Credit card companies have special cards for people with high credit rating, formerly in the form of "gold" or "platinum" cards, nowadays more likely "signature/world" or "infinite/world elite". Your credit card can signal wealth in the same way a rolex or expensive cuff link could. These cards come with a lot of extra perks (and costs) and are a thing of envy for a lot of people. On the other end of this spectrum we find the debit card which, fair or not, seems to signal "bad credit" to a lot of people. Using debit cards can also have some unforeseen consequences when you accidentally overcharge your account, hefty fines *can* ensue.

**In the EU**, credit cards are used far less then they are in the US. Also afaik (and someone will correct me if I'm wrong) they tend to have a lot less perks in way of discounts for gas and the likes. The two major payment methods are cash and *debit* cards.

These debit cards are not issued by card companies like credit cards usually are, but by banks and they are directly linked to your (checking) account. Life without such a card might be possible, but it will take some serious effort as this would also mean you have no bank account. I don't even know if this is even doable because I have honestly never met a EU citizen without a bank account.

You can overdraw a European debit card only to a set limit. This limit is set by your bank and there is only so much you can do to get this limit up, it depends mostly on income and possessions, or lack thereof. You can however always get them to set you limit to zero* (meaning no overdrafts) if you want to avoid paying the high interest rates on overdraft accounts. There are no extra fines when you go "in the red", however, when you reach your limit, your transactions will fail and you will not be able to withdraw cash with your card. Setting your limit to zero and never using any credit is a *positive* for your ability to borrow money. In the abstract, the difference seems to be that the US system judges you on the way you *handle* debt, whereas in the European system it's *how much debt you have* that is the deciding factor.

Finally, there is no culture to speak of surrounding debit cards in Europe, as they tell you nothing about the holder. Debit cards have no negative connotations. Everyone has one, it's simply a given. There is however some resentment towards credit cards, of which I am not free, given the fact that, especially for small business owners, the credit card companies charge pretty large fees (in the full procents per transaction) and their terms of service deny you the freedom to pass this on to the customer. Meaning that a credit card user makes you less money than another customer would, while paying the same amount. When your margins are thin, this becomes significant. Add to this that there exist a perfectly acceptable alternative and almost every retailer (wheter they will admit it or not) will prefer you using cash or debit card over credit cards.

<sub>* Setting the overdraft limit to zero: in Germany please read the small print. Many banks have an additional "tolerance" for overdraft on which interest is even more heavy than on approved overdraft credit. It is possible to get that set to 0 as well but there may be some discussion with the bank.</sub>

Comment: Apple Pay does not supplant a credit or debit card, it's an alternative to reading the card identification off the magnetic stripe (just like the EMV chip is an alternative to reading the magnetic stripe), and then the merchant uses the credit card network to perform the transaction in exactly the normal way.

Comment: Also, the naming of "special cards" has undergone some inflation -- gold cards are (with the exception of AmEx) now the bottom of the barrel and platinum cards haven't been "special" for a couple decades.  Today the widely-available special tiers are "signature"/"world" and "infinite"/"world elite" (often with "reserve" thrown into the product name although it isn't actually a credit card designation).  And then there are the invitation-only cards.

Comment: Although the "bank cards" (debit) are issued automatically, apparently you can have a bank account but not have a card issued. I take that from a recent letter I got about one account that I use exclusively for online transactions where the bank said as I haven't used the card so-and-so long, they won't issue a new one once the current one expires.

Comment: Setting the overdraft limit to zero: in Germany please read the small print. Many banks have an additional "tolerance" for overdraft on which interest is even more heavy than on approved overdraft credit. It is possible to get that set to 0 as well but there may be some discussion with the bank. In my experience, you may have to ask the bank to flag you as "Harz IV receiver" (i.e. being on social security money).

Comment: Premium credit cards also exist in Europe, but very few people have them. Because the annual fees are high and the rewards are modest, such cards only make sense if you value the perks sufficiently. In contrast, everyone and their dog seems to have a premium card in the US. With high rewards and low effective annual fees, premium cards often make sense to the ordinary middle class.

Comment: What happens to someone who can't/won't pay their overdraft balance?  I'm asking because similar situations are a common way to end up involuntarily unbanked in the US.

Comment: @DanisFiddlingbyFirelight: The bank can terminate that account and that will also give the customer a "bad credit" entry, but in the EU there's a right to have a "basic payment account". That is an account with strictly no overdraft, that a bank can refuse to open only on good reasons. A bank suing the customer because of the long overdrawn account probably has such good reasons, but the customer can get another one with any other bank.

Comment: @BenVoigt I updated my answer on the special cards, thanks. Did have a chuckle at "world elite" though, except from DT I can't imagine anyone using that card without feeling embarrassed :)

Comment: @cbeleitessupportsMonica I've updated my answer (with small print of course)

Comment: @DanisFiddlingbyFirelight In my experience, if this is you main checking account, they basically do nothing but... you won't be able to do anything with it until your balance is back to normal, this includes opening other accounts. But this is very rare as the limit is set in advance. You can be "in the red" almost indefinitely (lots of people are) and the banks won't mind at those interest rates.

Comment: *I have honestly never met a EU citizen without a bank account*, I have, when I rented a cottage in rural Spain, the landlord handled entirely in cash.  I suspect this varies a lot between different EU countries.

Comment: @gerrit I suppose it does. But I think you should consider the "fiscal advantages" of using cash. I had a similar experience in Greece not long ago, but I think our unplanned, one night stay in that B&B didn't meet the owners standard of what should be in his books :p

Comment: *The two major payment methods in the US are cash and credit cards, with cheques, debit cards and new developments like apple pay trailing behind* - do you have a reference that supports this?

Comment: Also, I'm trying to write this in a manner that doesn't come off as critical, but - while I can appreciate your intent to compare the EU to the US, your paragraphs describing the US are a little cringy and feel like exactly what they are (something written by someone not actually from the US.) Premium cards don't really have much cultural cache (except maybe as a joke, or in a rap video). No one looks down on people who use debit cards. And credit cards are only a (potentially small) part of what determines your credit score, while you've written as if they're the primary factor.

Comment: @dwizum 1. Yes, in fact it's the only thing I sourced, feeling that sourcing was both overkill and not a good use of my time at the time of writing.

Comment: @dwizum 2. About the cringyness, I suspect that is the same I cringe I feel reading all the answers written by Americans both here and especially in the other thread mentioned. I wanted to make the comparison exactly for that reason, because the amount of wrong advice given to Europeans on this site because of Americans not realizing they are the exception, not the norm in these matters is staggering.

Comment: @dwizum The cultural cache thing is debatable (I originally wrote I was gonna catch flack for it, but removed that sentence because until now I hadn't) I'll respectfully agree to disagree, I have experienced more of US culture than you might give me credit for. Since both our experiences are anecdotal, I'm gonna leave that one up. I guess you haven't experienced yuppie culture the way I have.

Comment: @dwizum And finally, I've edited my answer to reflect the fact that credit card use is not the only factor in determining your credit score, this was indeed an oversight. If someone would explain to me (and the rest of the world) how credit score _is_ calculated though, that would be great.

Comment: https://www.myfico.com/credit-education/whats-in-your-credit-score

Comment: @dwizum "Fair Isaac, the makers of the FICO score, is tight-lipped about exactly how the scores are calculated. But they do give the weight..." Would you please not feign ignorance about this controversy just to make me look bad?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure what ignorance or controversy you're talking about. You asked how credit scores were calculated. That website has pages of information explaining how they're calculated. I thought it would be helpful.

Comment: @dwizum I'm sorry I questioned your motives. The controversy is about the fact that while your credit score is a huge factor in what you can and can not do in the US, the way those scores are calculated is considered a trade secret. This means that US consumers are at the mercy of Fico and the likes, and while _theoretically_ they have alternatives, in practice they are forced to play a game of which they can't know the rules.

Comment: To be fair, the current approach to credit scoring is *vastly* more transparent and easier to understand than how lending decisions were made prior to universal acceptance of risk based lending. Although the literal formulas aren't published, there is a great deal of explanation around what factors are included and how they are weighted. Fair Issac goes as far as providing release-note style documentation about changes when they version the models.

Comment: And, again, I really don't mean to be critical, but there's a degree of irony in your answer - you are indicating that you are upset about Americans writing speculatively or ignorantly about Europe, but your answer comes off as a European writing somewhat speculatively or ignorantly about America. I'm trying to point that out in an effort to be helpful, not out of any desire to tear you down in any way.

Comment: Also, I just looked at a set of benchmarking data I have access to (at work) regarding consumer card transactions in the US. This is a data set made available to financial institutions for benchmarking their customers against the general public. Debit card use outweighs credit card use by nearly 4:1. So I'm not sure your claim about credit cards being used extensively compared to debit cards is accurate. I had a hunch that was the case, which is why I was wondering if you had a reference.

Comment: I think that "ignorance" is solely about the cultural reference, otherwise I have no idea where any of my answer would be incorrect. This is from personal experience, like I told you. You probably understand better than me that the US is huge and so diverse that someone from New England can be culturally closer to me than to their countrymen in Alabama or Texas. We're both just sharing anecdotes here.

Comment: @dwizum We crossed each other. The Wikipedia article I linked to tells a different story. I love data though, let's see what bigquery's public sets have to offer. I have no problem amending my answer if incorrect.

Comment: @dwizum It's got to be tomorrow though, it's 18:30 here and people are getting hungry.

Comment: *We're both just sharing anecdotes here* To be clear, I'm sharing things I know to be true because my career depends on me being right about them. I work in analytics (specifically around consumer behavior, marketing, lending, and fraud) in the financial industry in the US. Meanwhile, that Wikipedia article you linked to has a banner at the top stating that it has multiple issues, including a lack of citations or references.

Comment: If you want to continue this tomorrow, perhaps we should do it in chat so as to not drag the comments out any further.

Comment: "Not having a credit card, or not using it..." A third negative factor for credit is carrying *too much*, particularly by maxing out a credit line or carrying large card balances from month to month.

Comment: "In the EU, credit cards are used far less then they are in the US" - the amount of credit card use varies *hugely* by country.  I know that Germany uses credit cards much less than France for example.

Comment: @MartinBonnersupportsMonica Yes, it is hard to generalize the EU like this, but on a whole, the EU is lot less credit card minded than the US is. Also, income seems to be an even bigger factor, with CC ownership (cant be sure of usage) rising with income. And a lot of practices are, or are in the process of being, standardized by the EU, leading to smaller differences over time.

Comment: @dwizum I've dealt with shipping to consumers and all that surrounds it for many decades. Let's not make this a p. contest. Anyway, I've been looking for data to either verify or refute your claim. I learned a lot, with the best resource I could find being [this one](https://www.statista.com/statistics/568523/preferred-payment-methods-usa/) . The leading payment method in the US seems to be credit card, I could not find anything close to a 4:1 ratio, or even data that suggested debit cards are used more than credit cards. Finding trends was a lot harder, the use of debit cards seems...

Comment: .. to be both on the rise and on the decline, depending on who you ask. I did underestimate the prevalence of debit card usage in the US however, and I will be updating my answer accordingly.

Comment: @dwizum So, details aside, my answer seems to be a pretty accurate depiction of reality. Unless you want to dispute my main claims: 1. The US is more CC minded, whereas the EU is more DC minded and 2. The way credit works differs greatly between the US and the EU, I would like to leave it at that.

Comment: @Douwe I can't speak in detail to the situation in the EU personally, so I'm quite happy to take your word for it that things are different in the EU. But with respect to the US, I would still consider the corrections suggested to be important in terms of the accuracy of your answer. Also, I've just re-read your answer and noticed that your sentence *your credit rating is calculated from your assets and...* is incorrect. Assets aren't included in credit scoring models in the US.

Comment: Also, I hope you can take my comments in the spirit of suggesting helpful corrections. Since you seem really concerned about the accuracy of data representing the EU, and about the potential of Americans to mis-represent things, I think it's fair for me as an American to also be concerned about the accuracy of data representing the US.

Comment: @dwizum I've removed the "assets", since I only edited that part on your suggestion. I have never known any better then that credit score is calculated from how you handle credit + black box. [This](https://www.myfico.com/credit-education/whats-in-your-credit-score) says the same, with the five categories simply being different aspects of using credit. I thought you meant they now used a more sane approach, with your physical + financial assets as contributing factor and I didn't read the article as thoroughly as I should have.

Comment: @dwizum If I didn't take your comments in that spirit we wouldn't be having a conversation to begin with. You must however understand that I've put a serious effort in researching your claims but _factually_ it seems my answer holds. I can see how in your experience the cultural reference is wrong (even though I've seen salespeople ruthlessly discriminate customers on card type for example). I tried my very best to be as neutral as possible, I refrained from value judgments, and since we are not really debating any of the essence of what I'm saying, this will have to do.

Answer (score 2):

In the United States, there are separate laws regulating credit cards versus debit cards, the Fair Credit Billing Act and the Electronic Funds Transfer Act.

While a specific business can implement a policy that often is kinder as a commercial practice (e.g. $0 liability for either, especially for high net worth customers), under the law the cardholder's liability for a fraud against them is capped at $50 for credit and $500 for debit.

As discussed elsewhere on [money.se](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/67368/would-i-ever-need-credit-card-if-my-debit-card-is-issued-by-mastercard-visa)

Answer (score 1):

There are three main types of cards in the US: credit, debit, and prepaid. There are also charge cards, but they are rare nowadays. There are also ATM cards, but those have largely merged with debit cards.

A credit card accesses a line of credit. The issuing bank pays the merchant, and then the amount of the purchase is money you owe the issuing bank.

A debit card accesses a bank account, usually a checking account. There are various laws that treat cards differently based on the type, for instance the [Durbin Amendment](https://www.investopedia.com/terms/d/durbin-amendment.asp) places restrictions on debit card interchange that don't apply to credit cards.

A prepaid also accesses a bank account, but generally there is little to no way to access the account other than through the card. One description is "a prepaid account is a checking account without the checking". With cards being more secure than checks, and Know Your Customer laws not being as stringent for prepaid versus debit cards, sometimes someone who isn't able to get a checking account will be able to get a prepaid card (although often with extra fees). Prepaid cards are also often used for payments. For instance, in California, Unemployment Insurance payments are issued on a prepaid card, and many companies provide a prepaid card option rather than paychecks. One major player in the prepaid space is [ADP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ADP_(company)).

Gift cards can be handled as prepaid cards, but if the card is for a specific merchant, then there's no real need for a network (although a merchant might decide to use the existing networks rather than set their own system up). So, for instance, a Visa gift card is definitely a prepaid card, and the punchcard that I bought prepaying several dance lessons is just a piece of cardboard. A Starbucks gift card, on the other hand, I don't know.

Charge cards are like credit cards, except that you're supposed to pay the balance at the end of the month.

> I've also read between the lines that credit cards might be issued not only by banks but other businesses too.

The industry is moving towards the more inclusive term "financial institution". Credit cards are, as far as I know, almost all issued by banks, but most institutions that have checking accounts will offer debit cards for them, so not only banks but also credit unions will have debit cards.

In industry lingo, whatever FI is handling the account and paying out money to the merchants is called the "issuer", but you may be using the word "issue" in a more general sense of who sends you the card, or whose branding is on it. Cards can have several different brandings on them: there's the network, the issuing bank, and often some other company that's involved. For instance, there are credit cards that are branded "Amazon" cards that are backed by Chase Bank and are Visa network.

> and it's the bank account that has the credit feature, not the card.

A card is just a mechanism for accessing an account. It is the account, not the card per se, that has the credit feature. The term "bank account" is, at least in the US, generally understood to refer to a checking or savings account. A credit card account is an account, and it is handled by a bank, so technically it's a "bank account", but referring to it as such would be confusing.